# Linq query to get the properties from object B which have the same name and type of object A

Tags: c#, .net, linq, reflection

I'm on a interop scenario, and because of that I'm dealing with structures and classes used like structures in different assemblies - so a cast is not enough and have to do manually field-by-field which is very boring and error prone.

So I devised an function that does copy the great deal of simple fields/properties and I deal only with the troubled ones.

When I do this to properties only, it works ok. But I need now how to fix this `LiNQ` query to be able to get a list of fields from the source object and join them with the properties on the target object.

Code below:

```
    var TypeOrig = pSource.GetType();
    var TypeDest = pTarget.GetType();
    var TypeString = typeof(System.String);

    var PropOrig = TipoOrig.GetFields(); // if it is GetProperties instead 
                                         // of GetFields works OK
    var PropDest = TipoDest.GetProperties();

    var QryPropVT =
      from
        POrig in PropOrig
      join PDest in PropDest
        on new
        {
            POrig.Name,
            POrig.FieldType
        } equals new
        {
            PDest.Name,
            PDest.PropertyType
        }
      where POrig.PropertyType.IsValueType || (POrig.PropertyType.Equals(TipoString))
      select new
      {
          PropO = POrig,
          PropD = PDest
      };
```

`Visual C# error: Error 2 The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect.  Type inference failed in the call to 'Join'.`

EDIT: I saw value injector, but it's like using a Death Star to kill a mosquito...[/EDIT]

Comment: Will they *always* be fields in the original type and properties in the target type? Or might there be a mixture? Additionally, your code would be much easier to read if you'd follow normal .NET naming conventions, and use `camelCase` for your local variables...

Comment: @JonSkeet: _Or might there be a mixture?_ In creating this function I'm covering these other two scenarios. _you'd follow normal .NET naming conventions_ - I program in three different platforms everyday and when I have to create code from scratch, I tried really hard to convey the conventions in recent past. In the end, the mess that attempts created made me choose one convention - the one that

Comment: @JonSkeet: (continued) I can convey without having to stop and adjust again: object pascal. The above code is an excerpt from real code I've done on job. I'll try to convey to .NET conventions when I publish on SO...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your join statement appears to be creating 2 different anonymous types since one has a property called `FieldType` and one has a property called `PropertyType`. LINQ is unable to do the join unless both types have the exact same fields in the exact same order. There is a wonderful article on this [found here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/262949/Linq-Join-on-Mutiple-columns-using-Anonymous-type).

In which case you'll need to do this for your join:

```
join PDest in PropDest
        on new
        {
            Name = POrig.Name,
            JoinType = POrig.FieldType
        } equals new
        {
            Name = PDest.Name,
            JoinType = PDest.PropertyType
        }
```

Comment: Great chances of it working. But I'll only have chance of testing it tomorrow!! Nice.

Comment: Worked nicely! +1, accept. SO only allows to reward the bounty in 2 hours.

Comment: Bounty rewarded as it must be.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be after AutoMapper. http://automapper.codeplex.com/ or Value Injector http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/

**Value Injector example:**

```
myObject.InjectFrom(anyOtherObject);

//inject from multiple sources
a.InjectFrom(b,c,d,e);

//inject using your own injection
a.InjectFrom<MyInjection>(b);
```